# Dynamically generate angular module for environment variables

Tags: angularjs, environment-variables

The only thing I can find is **gulp-ng-config**. But I'd like to avoid using gulp as a build tool in my project.

Is there any way to run **gulp-ng-config** using npm run command? If not, are there any npm modules that can achieve similar?

Comment: why do you want to use environment variable to build your web?

Comment: Hi Simon, environment variables are stuff like db connection strings, API urls etc. These values are different between dev/staging/prod.